# How to use a shared Mailbox configured in Lotus Notes to send messages?

Tags: vb6, lotus-notes

I have an application in VB6 using Lotus Notes so send emails to various recipients.
This is a heavy applications that sends daily reports and since it's a rather heavy task, there is a dedicated machine running it.
It has a win user logged in and the Lotus session that is being used, is the one related to the WIN user. Email messages are sent by the user who has a Lotus/Win session.

Now, this user has access to a shared Mailbox in Lotus.  I want the email to be sent from this new shared Mailbox. I can do it manualy, and I noticed that the message is sent from the main email of this shared mailbox but is adds below it the fiedl "sent from UserX". 
This is the situation that I want to automate.

I've this (VB6) code:

```
'Start a session to notes
Set Session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
'Get the sessions username and then calculate the mail file name
UserName = Session.UserName
MailDbName = Left(UserName, 1) & Right(UserName, (Len(UserName) - InStr(1, UserName, " "))) & ".nsf"
'Open the mail database in notes
Set Maildb = Session.GETDATABASE("", MailDbName)
```

I think I need to change this last line where I choose the `MailDbName`.

Can anyone give me some guideance, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The MailDbName is a string that contains the path and filename of the mail database within the server, for example `"mail/user.nsf"`.  In this case, the server is local, since the first parameter of the GETDATABASE method is passing an empty string.  You can replace that with a server name if the database is on the server.

If you open the shared mail database and look at File > Database > Properties you can see the server and file path information and use that in this method call.

However, if the email is sent programmatically, you may need to [check out this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676368/lotusscript-from-address-when-sending-email-as-web-user/10676749#10676749) on how to make the "From" appear as someone different.