# Eliminate server name from from "From" field in documents sent through the Agent

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus

I've an agent which runs everyday and sends email notifications. I'd like that it will run on behalf of specific user, for example "Joe Waker/New Yourk/BTC" and this name will be displayed in field "From". But when agent sends mails it appears as "Joe Waker/New Yourk/BTC@SERVERNAME", how can I eliminate this @SERVERNAME and leave only "Joe Waker/New Yourk/BTC"? 
I've tried to change value of field Principal and change value in properties of agent in field "run on behalf on", but didn't success. 
If anybody know the solution please share, thank you.

Comment: Did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676368/lotusscript-from-address-when-sending-email-as-web-user/16860559

Answer (score 0):

You could simply run the agent using your regular application signer ID (the one you use to sign all your production code), and use the trick of depositing the mail directly in mail.box. Then you can set the "from" field to anything you like.

You can take a look at my mail notification class here:
http://blog.texasswede.com/lotusscript-mail-notification-class/