# Sending Lotus Notes email through C# hiding SentBy field

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

I have developed code,in C#, which sends email in Lotus Notes.
I want SentBy(From field) in the email to be hidden. I have user the Principal field to make Custom field.

```
NotesDocument doc = db.CreateDocument();              
 doc.ReplaceItemValue("Form", "Memo");               
 doc.ReplaceItemValue("SendTo", richTextBox1.Text.Trim().Split(','));  
 doc.ReplaceItemValue("Subject", richTextBox3.Text);  
 doc.ReplaceItemValue("Principal", "Test Demo");  
 NotesRichTextItem _richTextItem = doc.CreateRichTextItem("Body");
 _richTextItem.AppendText(richTextBox4.Text + "\r\n");  
 doc.SaveMessageOnSend = true;  
 if (this.check)             
    doc.Send(false);  
 MessageBox.Show("Mail Sent successfully");
```

The above code sends email perfectly but it doesn't hide the SentBy (From field). Sent By ( From field) always shows the name of the person running this code along with the Principal. Can this be hidden so that only the Principal field, here Test Demo, is only visible.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be hidden if you're using the NotesDocument.Send() method. (IBM Domino is an enterprise email system, so it doesn't make spoofing senders easy.)

It can be hidden if you write the message directly to the Domino server's mail.box file. That's not supported by IBM, though, so if you do that you're on your own if you do anything that screws up email routing and delivery. You can find a link to sample code that does it, though, in one of the answers to [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676368/lotusscript-from-address-when-sending-email-as-web-user).