# Best way to change the sender name?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

My environment is configured for Directory Assistance so users from our LDAP can also authenticate to our Domino applications.

The issue I have is that the the current user that is returned has this format:
**uid=abc@mail.com/ou=customers/DC=ACME/DC=COM** so when

> emailDocument.send()

is triggered; the From feld gets populated with this value and the SMTP communication fails when doing the domain lookup with this message = **Data format error**

I'm using [emailBean from Tony McGuckin](https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=emailbean-send-dominodocument-html-emails-cw-embedded-images-attachments-custom-headerfooter) for sending emails.

Is there an alternative way to change the Sender name like **noreply@mycompany.com**?

I'm trying to avoid to create the message directly on mail.box.

Comment: When sending mail from C# in Visual Studio there is an SMTP client class that can be used to set the sender.  works really nice even when sending through Domino and is super easy. doing the same using Lotusscript, java, ssjs is a real pain. and have been so for 20 years.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what your use case is:

- You want to have "proper" eMails individually per user
- The application sends out eMails with a single sender name

In the first case an address book entry for your users is needed where you can map the external name to a proper Full name and eMail.

In the later case: use creation in the mail.box. It's your best option

Comment: ... or use the field "Principal" field (you must remember the domain) - see more in answer two on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676368/lotusscript-from-address-when-sending-email-as-web-user